# Issue in passing a string from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

Background : I am trying to develop my first android application which is a student discussion panel. I am good with PHP and MySQL but don't have much experience in android Java.

Issue: 
In SelectedQuestionActivity class, if I simply give the URL as http://thewbs.getfreehosting.co.uk/talky/fetchans.php?qid=3, it works just fine and it fetches the corresponding answer to the question. 
But if I do it the way I have shown in the code below, the application crashes. I am not sure where I am wrong.

CODE: 
AllQuestionActivity.java

```
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.qid)).getText()
                    .toString();
             //pid is the value of the selected question for example www.example.com/fetchans?qid=3 so here pid value is supposed to be 3. 
            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SelectedQuestionActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
```

Now in SelectedQuestionActivity.java
code:

```
public class SelectedQuestionActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

Intent intent = getIntent();
String qid = intent.getExtras().getString(TAG_PID);
// url to get all products list
private String url_all_products = "http://thewbs.getfreehosting.co.uk/talky/fetchans.php?qid="+qid;

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "ques";
private static final String TAG_PID = "aid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "aname";
private static final String TAG_INFO = "answer";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_ans);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();
 }
  class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SelectedQuestionActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Answers. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Answers: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String info = c.getString(TAG_INFO);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_INFO, info);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } 
            else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SelectedQuestionActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_selected_ques, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_INFO, TAG_DATE },
                        new int[] { R.id.aid, R.id.aname, R.id.answer, R.id.date});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

   }
  }
```

JSONparser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to post your error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are trying to getIntent outside onCreate of ListActivity so move it inside onCreate method as :

```
 Intent intent;
String qid;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_ans);

       // get Intent here 
      intent = getIntent();
      qid = intent.getExtras().getString(TAG_PID);

       // your code here
```

and also no need to use `runOnUiThread` method for updating UI from `onPostExecute` because onPostExecute method called on Ui thread we can access UI elements in it

**EDIT:-**

you are not adding any paramter to NameValuePair inside doInBackground . add quid before sending it to makeHttpRequest as :

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
 // Building Parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
add quid param here
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qid",qid));  //<<<< add here
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                      url_all_products,
                      "GET", 
                      params);
// your code here
```

Comment: Yes thanks it worked. Solved the crashing problem pretty well. But somehow it is not sending the correct value in "qid".

Comment: @Bhavyanshu : `it is not sending the correct value in "qid"` mean can u plz explain it more

Comment: Logcat showing 
  `{"success":0,"message":"No answer yet. Kindly check back later!"}`
This means incorrect value of qid is being passed.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu : can u tell me which quid is passed when u are getting this response from server

Comment: Logcat is not showing that. Right now i have an answer at qid=3. You can visit the URL i have stated in the question. But when i select the 3rd question within the android application, it's showing the message stated above. So this clearly means everything else is working fine but it's just this "qid" in the URL which is not getting the correct value from previous activity.

Comment: Still not working. Logcat still showing the same message. Is there a way i can come to know what value the qid is getting? Just to check.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu : now code if f9 you will need to debug application using Log and check what exactly you are hitting to get data from server. just make some log inside onCreate and doInBackground methods

Comment: @Bhavyanshu : most welcome friend. can i known why u are not getting right json

Comment: Yeah sure. Well you see in AllQuestionAcitivity.java the TAG_PID is not in quotation marks. So i just used "TAG_PID".
 `Intent myIntent = new Intent(AllQuestionActivity.this,SelectedQuestionActivity.class);myIntent.putExtra("TAG_PID", pid);`
  `AllQuestionActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);`
and then in doinBackground i used
`qid = intent.getExtras().getString("TAG_PID");` That solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string from one activity object to another , while you didn't write code to receive it on the new activity in the right place.
To solve this you should add some code to your onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.all_ans);
       String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
       if (url != null)
        url_all_products = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should need to get your intent values in `onCreate()` as below :

> ```
> @Override
>   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>        setContentView(R.layout.all_ans);
>         Intent intent = getIntent();
>       String qid = intent.getExtras().getString(TAG_PID);
>     }
> ```